# How to resolve changing pointer value in function call? Is this a cgo bug?

Tags: c, go, cgo

I'm calling a C function via cgo thusly:

```
var _outptr_7 C.double 
var _outptr_8 C.double  
var kk uintptr = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&_outptr_7))
gogsl.InitializeGslFunction(f)
_result := int32(C.gsl_integration_qags((*C.gsl_function)(unsafe.Pointer(f.CPtr())), C.double(a), C.double(b), C.double(epsabs), C.double(epsrel), C.size_t(limit), (*C.gsl_integration_workspace)(unsafe.Pointer(workspace.Ptr())), (*C.double)(&_outptr_7), (*C.double)(&_outptr_8)))
fmt.Printf("%10.10X\n",kk)
return _result, *(*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(&_outptr_7)), *(*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(&_outptr_8))
```

Now, the `kk` is here for debugging purposes.  I've modified the C function `gsl_integration_qags` to output the 8th argument it receives (that's `&_outptr_7`, the `_<n>` count from 0!)

(The `InitializeGslFunction` can be ignored for the purpose here...)

The two values - `kk` and the C function output - match exactly.

However, I get a *different* number out than the C function returns - it sets the 8th argument via indirection.   I'm sure this is correct, I've watched it work in gdb.

It looks like this: (omitting lines that just read `(gdb)` where I hit enter to repeat command)

```
Breakpoint 3, qags (f=0xc20800a260, a=0, b=1, epsabs=0, epsrel=9.9999999999999995e-08, limit=1000, workspace=0x782ec0, result=0xc208031e28, abserr=0xc208031e20, q=0x7ffff79ad12c <gsl_integration_qk21>)
 at qags.c:479
479   *result = res_ext;
(gdb) n
480   *abserr = err_ext;
(gdb) p *result
$1 = -4.0000000000000853
(gdb) p result
$2 = (double *) 0xc208031e28
(gdb) n
482   if (err_ext == GSL_DBL_MAX)
485   if (error_type || error_type2)
513     double max_area = GSL_MAX_DBL (fabs (res_ext), fabs (area)); 
515     if (!positive_integrand && max_area < 0.01 * resabs0)
520     double ratio = res_ext / area;
522     if (ratio < 0.01 || ratio > 100.0 || errsum > fabs (area))
526   goto return_error;
535   if (error_type > 2) 
540   if (error_type == 0) 
542       return GSL_SUCCESS;
573 }
gsl_integration_qags (f=0xc20800a260, a=0, b=1, epsabs=0, epsrel=9.9999999999999995e-08, limit=1000, workspace=0x782ec0, result=0xc208031e28, abserr=0xc208031e20) at qags.c:53
53    return status ;
54  }
```

// Correct value (-4.0) is being returned from C function.

```
_cgo_3ce45c051e63_Cfunc_gsl_integration_qags (v=0xc208031db8) at /home/dtrombley/go/src/github.com/dtromb/gogsl/numint/numint.go:241
asmcgocall () at /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:669
669     MOVQ    48(SP), DI
670     MOVQ    (g_stack+stack_hi)(DI), SI
671     SUBQ    40(SP), SI
672     MOVQ    DI, g(CX)
673     MOVQ    SI, SP
asmcgocall () at /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:674
674     RET
runtime.asmcgocall_errno () at /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:627
627     MOVL    AX, ret+16(FP)
runtime.asmcgocall_errno () at /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:628
628     RET
runtime.cgocall_errno (fn=0x405210 <_cgo_3ce45c051e63_Cfunc_gsl_integration_qags>, arg=0xc20805fdb8, ~r2=0) at /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/cgocall.go:132
132     exitsyscall()
134     return errno
```

//  cgo C glue is about to return from call into Go caller

```
github.com/dtromb/gogsl/numint._Cfunc_gsl_integration_qags (p0=0xc20800a260, p1=0, p2=1, p3=0, p4=9.9999999999999995e-08, p5=1000, p6=0x782ec0, p7=0xc20805fe28, p8=0xc20805fe20, r1=0)
at /home/dtrombley/go/src/github.com/dtromb/gogsl/numint/:92
92  /home/dtrombley/go/src/github.com/dtromb/gogsl/numint/: No such file or directory.
```

// Bang, it's broken.  p7 value in return val struct is /different than the value that went in/... **the location of _outptr_7 has changed**.

```
(gdb) p p7
$3 = (github.com/dtromb/gogsl/numint._Ctype_double *) 0xc20805fe28
(gdb) p *p7
$4 = 0
(gdb) n
github.com/dtromb/gogsl/numint.Qags (f=0xc20805ff58, a=0, b=1, epsabs=0, epsrel=9.9999999999999995e-08, limit=1000, workspace=0xc20800a1d0, ~r7=7753968, ~r8=0, ~r9=0)
at /home/dtrombley/go/src/github.com/dtromb/gogsl/numint/numint.go:75
75     fmt.Printf("%10.10X\n",kk)
C208031E28
76     return _result, *(*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(&_outptr_7)), *(*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(&_outptr_8))
(gdb) p _outptr_7
$5 = 0
(gdb) p &_outptr_7
$6 = (float64 *) 0xc20805fe28
```

// But the correct value is still hanging out there.

```
 (gdb) p $1
 $7 = -4.0000000000000853
```

So, what gives?   What is going on here?  How to fix/workaround?

Here is the cgo binding showing the struct mapping, for completeness:

```
void
_cgo_a9ebceabba03_Cfunc_gsl_integration_qags(void *v)
{
    struct {
            gsl_function* p0;
            double p1;
            double p2;
            double p3;
            double p4;
            size_t p5;
            gsl_integration_workspace* p6;
            double* p7;
            double* p8;
            int r;
            char __pad76[4];
    } __attribute__((__packed__, __gcc_struct__)) *a = v;
    char *stktop = _cgo_topofstack();
    __typeof__(a->r) r = gsl_integration_qags((void*)a->p0, a->p1, a->p2, a->p3, a->p4, a->p5, (void*)a->p6, (void*)a->p7, (void*)a->p8);
    a = (void*)((char*)a + (_cgo_topofstack() - stktop));
    a->r = r;
}
```

The bug occurs or does not occur randomly depending on some details of the compilation which should not affect semantics - adding a line which prints out &_outptr_7 before calling the C function causes it to return correctly, for example.   Making other changes to the code reverts it back, etc etc.

Something I'm doing wrong?  Or bug in cgo?

Comment: Have you tested the go1.5 rc to see if it behaves any differently? Can you supply a complete, runnable example? I don't see anything else obvious, but this is more of a question for the mailing list if you want some debugging help (though things may be a little slow with the impending release).

Comment: Tried the mailing list, no response (my msg didn't even post- maybe mods are busy or something).  I don't want debugging help - I want to know if the address of that value changing (a simple "var x <type>" on the Go stack) as demonstrated  is legitimate/intended behavior or not.   The question is "is this a bug"?

Comment: Haven't tried development / bleeding edge Go.   If I could make a minimal test case, I would have used it here - as I said this thing happens randomly, on some builds yes and on some builds no - and involves a popular (large) C library....

Comment: (Happy to replicate my testing environment on a temporary cloud instance if anyone familiar with cgo internals wants to play with it in situ)

Comment: If I move _outptr_7 to the global scope, there is no problem (the value does not change).   If I add a line that prints out the value of &_outptr_7 /after/ the C call, there is no problem (the value does not change).... =/

Comment: Compiling with gccgo also eliminates the problem.   That's my workaround for now.

Comment: As I suggested, have you tried go1.5 yet? It may be escape analysis related, which there are fixes in place. Go pointers need to be alive for the entire lifetime of a cgo call, but this didn't always happen for stack allocated values in go1.4 that were marked as non-escaping.

Comment: Yeah, 1.5 also fixes it - and what you are saying makes sense with regard to what I'm seeing.   Thanks for the suggestion.  Is there a specific related bug 1.5 addresses that you know of?

Comment: It was probably https://golang.org/issue/10303

Comment: Awesome, make that an answer if you like.  TYVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Go 1.4.  Fixed in 1.5.

https://golang.org/issue/10303